# Looping through a subset of worksheets with vba does not work

Tags: vba, foreach, subset, worksheet

I'm trying to insert two rows in a subset of worksheets in a workbook by defining a range in a worksheet and loop through the worksheets in that range, but the code will only run on the active worksheet.

```
Sub StatePIPData()
Dim sheet_name As Range
For Each sheet_name In Sheets("WS").Range("A:A")
    If sheet_name.Value = "" Then
        Exit For
    Else
         'Insert 2 rows for 2011 and 2012's data
         Range("A14").EntireRow.Insert
         Cells(14, 1) = Cells(15, 1) + 1
         Range("A14").EntireRow.Insert
         Cells(14, 1) = Cells(15, 1) + 1
         End If
    Next sheet_name
 End Sub
```

Any thoughts on how I could get this loop to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it what you need?

```
Sub StatePIPData()
    Dim sheet_name As Range
    Dim sh As Worksheet

    For Each sheet_name In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("WS").Range("A:A")
        If sheet_name.Value = "" Then
            Exit For
        Else
            On Error Resume Next
            Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheet_name)
            On Error GoTo 0

            If Not sh Is Nothing Then
                With sh
                    'Insert 2 rows for 2011 and 2012's data
                    .Range("A14").EntireRow.Insert
                    .Cells(14, 1) = .Cells(15, 1) + 1
                    .Range("A14").EntireRow.Insert
                    .Cells(14, 1) = .Cells(15, 1) + 1
                End With
            End If
        End If
    Next sheet_name
 End Sub
```

Comment: What you posted the first time :Sub StatePIPData()
    Dim sheet_name As Range
    For Each sheet_name In Sheets("Sheet5").Range("A:A")
        If sheet_name.Value = "" Then
            Exit For
        Else
             With Sheets(sheet_name.Value)
                'Insert 2 rows for 2011 and 2012's data
                .Range("A14").EntireRow.Insert
                .Cells(14, 1) = .Cells(15, 1) + 1
                .Range("A14").EntireRow.Insert
                .Cells(14, 1) = .Cells(15, 1) + 1
             End With
        End If
    Next sheet_name
 End Sub

Comment: can you specify what problem do you have with this code?

Comment: did exactly what I needed. Thanks!!! Do you think your edit is more efficient in some way?

Comment: Yup! it checks whether sheet with name `sheet_name` is really exist:)

Comment: How exactly do I do that?

Comment: I've run into another problem that I was wondering if you could help me with. I have another similar macro that references many cells in this manor: .Cells(14, 5) = (Cells(30, 19)). For some reason the target cells are left blank when I run that macro in a combined macro. It works when I run it on its own. Any thoughts as to why?

Comment: actually it's hard to find the problem without seeing the code..try to fully qualify your cells: `Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(14, 5) = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(30, 19)`. If it doesn't help maybe it's better to post new answer and show your code?